# Is the a bias here in closing / voting on questions

Tags: discussion

I really do think there is, but really it's on a case by case basis (oh look another question closed etc. for unclear or unsound reasons) so it's very nebulas.

I'd really like to hear what people think about whether there is a bias and of what sort.

Tentatively: I suppose people dislike questions of the sort that they themselves can't answer.

Comment: I agree with the 'mathematician', there are various case by case biases enacted by some of the priveledged users. I wrote a question about the A.C.D.C song with the lyrics who made who and it was closed and made so no further comments could be made by just two users, Cort Amon and another. It's funny because Cort Amon replied a lot trying to debate my points. He even said he was surprised the debating wasn't moved to the chat room earlier. I guess Cort Amon found a like minded user to make my further commenting disappear....

Comment: i think the fact this has four downvotes and two close votes is quite helpful in proving its point, that a contingent of its users are control freaks

Comment: I would also use the phrase elitist intellectuals who like have their points of view dominant on the questions that interest them..

Comment: If the supposed bias only exists on a nebulous case by case basis, then how can it be a systematic bias?

Comment: i don't think you need to know what a bias is to know there is a bias, certainly not for there to be a bias. something isn't right

Comment: On a more constructive note: it might be worthwhile highlighting (here) which questions you've noted have been closed as demonstrating bias.

Comment: @201044: there's nothing to my mind quoting lyrics (I've generally quoted literature and poets); but a philosophical point needs to be shown and justified; and the easiest way of doing this, is by tying it to the philosophical literature or other high-quality sources; such as the IEP or SEP.

Comment: When I mention the idea of philosophical concepts suggested by lyrics of modern music I'm referring to a kind of appeal to 'naive philosophy' that exists in popular media and culture. I know real philosophical analysis is held to high standards yet 'average' people are often 'instructed' in subtle ways about various 'suggestions of philosophical concepts without the benefit of an accurate analysis of what ideas are useful and what are opinionated or improper. Should academics let modern music inform people on what philosophical ideas or naive approximations of such be deemed valuable?

Comment: Has anyone written a book or article on all the wrong philosophical ideas one can pick up from modern music?

Comment: It seems any 'meritocracy driven' website is inherently not collaborative  unless some editors really like the question or responses involved..

Comment: @201044 whatever the merits of closing questions which annoy you (ETC) there's just no point in arguing about it really - i've tried hah

Comment: Any 'meritocracy- based' site like this one is really a  question and final answer site.  If a question is asked and deemed acceptable it is given a final answer by some user- editor who might sound like an expert.  The answer is supposed to be final no matter how it is put. So if patronizing the questioner will probably respond. The editors not wanting any debate will respond again and so on.. Debate like this wastes time and energy and it is not a  learning environment for any questioner if they are focusing on defending their views. So sites like this should be called a 'Q and F.A.' site.

Answer (score 2):

There is bias, but I think this is because of the demographic that are attracted - scientific and technically literate; but not generally philosophically sophisticated.

This is why for example the site attracts a disproportionate number of questions on logic, and this mostly on various flavours of *formal* logic, but not philosophical; for example I've not seen any questions on Priors tensed logic, or Hegels onto-logic; and why some of my own pointed questions on Parmenides and Zeno which is to defend Hegels onto-logic is possibly misconstrued as an attack on formal logic; or on science itself.

I've only noticed (on the whole) that poor-quality questions have been closed:

Sometimes this is because there are *too* many questions in the question, and for this reason there is insufficient coherence; in which case one ought to ask several smaller ones;

Or questions are not using philosophical vocabulary appropriately, in which case the question ought to ask how it should be deployed;

Or questions are asked in which the substance has been submerged by style (this is tempting when one admires a philosopher with a certain style) in which case simplify: it's far better to ask the good simple question hiding behind a complicated one; and one should recall style is achieved in combination with substance; and is never as easy as it may look.

Or questions lack reference to the philosophical literature; ie how a certain word is used, say sovereignty or absolute by Hobbes.

Because of the high ratio of inefficient questions in the above senses; at one point I would try to extract or find a good question in them; but on the whole I found this bad practise, as it only appeared to encourage more bad questions.

For example, I don't have anything against Nietzsche; but I recall when I first began on this site that most questions on Nietzsche invoked 'The Superman' or 'The Herd' - these would be his own disciples that he warned against; I'd be interested myself on seeing good questions on Nietszche specifically focused on his texts.

It's also, I think because of the demographic attracted that we don't get many good questions from the continental tradition: ie on Levinas, Gadamer, Kearney or Foucault.

The real question is how to encourage breadth and diversity; depth and focus.

Personally speaking, I don't have any formal philosophical training; but I tend to judge questions by the tradition in which I have been trained - mathematical and physical - but this not in a *literal* manner but by *analogy*, so similar standards of diversity, coherence, style, focus and reference to tradition.

Comment: There are obviously a lot of philosophical or grammatical or syntactic or semantic , e.t.c., errors to be corrected in many of the attempted philosophical questions that have been written. And if an editor chooses to help with a question that though poorly written might have interesting or important elements within it by suggesting improvements that's great. But the way suggestions are done is important here ( as with any meritocracy- driven sites.) If they are suggestions in a constructive or encouraging way GREAT. Yet if discouraging or patronizing this will cause endless debates ..

Comment: @201044: very well said - and I don't disagree.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example : [Is it possible that I see color differently?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/27902/is-it-possible-that-i-see-color-differently)

Closed as a duplicate. 
Clearly not a duplicate. 
Question is relevant to the stack.

Comment: Not so clearly not a duplicate. It's also a question that doesn't turn out to be very philosophically interesting, because the answer is "sure" what I see as "blue" and what you see as "blue" (meaning here our respective qualitative experiences) might be different, but there's not much interesting there. Odds on, they aren't. / I'm surprised we haven't already had it, but I'm willing to accept the judgment of the many that it's not a duplicate of a clearer question about colors and perception.

Comment: The point is that langauge could not communicate  the problem even if they had the problem, because when person 1 took their kindergarten colors worksheets, and pointed at "blue" they experienced red. But person 2 points at "blue" and experiences blue.

Comment: That really doesn't make much sense. Both of them experience what they will call "blue" because the word they associate with the experience is what the language identifies by the term "blue". That they have qualitatively different experiences is to say that the experience of blue for each of them differs. The label "red" doesn't attach for anyone. It could only attach under the circumstance where the qualitative experience of one person's "blue" is perfectly identical with what the rest of us experience with "red."

Comment: For me "sure" is not sufficient,  perhaps you think the arguement is closed so easily. Your last sentence of the comment above is exactly the issue, do you that that sentence p is ~♢p?

Comment: I would say yes, clearly, it is not a duplicate, and should either be reopened, or put on hold for some other reason. The semantics of q1 is != the semantics of q2. Even before my attempted edit.

Comment: What do you think the word "semantics" means in your comment here?

Comment: Also why on earth would I equate p and not possibly p?

Comment: Maybe, you're not following, but it's really not complicated. There's two problems: (1) there's not much of an argument - if you keep the layers straight: (a) the phenomenon that occurs in the world, (b) the qualitative experience of that phenomenon, and (c) the names in any given language for particular phenomenon regardless of individual qualitative experience. Sure, people can have different (b) potentially but what's **philosophically** interesting about that? as in what can one provide that is an objective helpful answer beyond that?

Comment: Are you saying proposition p is not possible? 

Obviously the asker found it philosophically interesting enough to ask the question.

Comment: It's not clear the OP has a grasp on what qualifies as philosophically interesting. It's clear they found it interesting and that they think it's philosophy. But again, it's not clear they understand what philosophy is. / also what proposition are you calling p?

Comment: @virmaior "not philosophically interesting"  -- to you (and maybe most sensible/serious philosophers).  That doesn't (imho) make it a bad question; it is a classic drunken philosophy question.  Having it on the site, with good answers, "makes the internet a better place".  The good answer might be your argument that, this supposedly deep question, is in fact, nonsense.

Comment: @virmaior if (b) varies from individual to individual, it is philosophically interesting since it is the qualia analog to Quine's gavagai argument in the philosphy of language.

Comment: @Dave that's actually the most convincing thing anyone has said in support of the question. Also, it's been edited which I think makes it a little clearer. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Dave ; what is a 'drunken philosophy question' and can they be of value?

Comment: @201044 Better term might have been *armchair philosophy*; "Armchair philosophy is amateur philosophy that arises from casual discussions." ( as described here https://www.quora.com/What-is-armchair-philosophy )
That term slipped my mind; and for me at least, alcohol is often involved.

Comment: @201044 While not perfect questions in terms of the content goals, they'll usually be to loose/broad compared to what are generally considered good questions.  Some will just always be too loose/broad (e.g. "What is love?"), but others, like this one, can be connected to mainstream (academic) philosophical thought.  These questions and answers can also be useful in promoting the site since they will reach a wide audience.

Comment: Can armchair philosophy bring up important philosophical points in an 'intuitive' non-formal fashion?

Comment: @201044 yes (imho); and further, there are a subset of questions raised in these kinds of non-formal theorizing that are appropriate for this forum.

Comment: So a type of 'armchair philosophy' though sometimes sloppy in presentation and any relevant reference points can point out interesting philosophical concepts or questions , that if further developed might be very useful. Are there any books that teach philosophy with this informal approach ? ( not in the sense that it only teaches  just an informal summary that can never lead to 'serious' philosophical ideas.)

Comment: Have any such recent armchair philosophy 'musings' come up with important philosophical principles that later have had all the relevant important philosophical details 'filled in'  , by experts?

Answer (score -3):

There is a clear bias on this site, but at this time I do not see anything that can be done about it.

Comment: If more users who can see biases complained about it then maybe the users in charge would change their policies..

Comment: the site does a good job of making sure people don't complain, because they just get anonymous close votes

Comment: How are close votes anonymous? It gives the names of people who vote to close.

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN all close votes are disclosed...

Comment: Saying that bias exists, without further explaining its nature to those of us who don't see it, isn't helpful for improving the site.

Comment: @hellyale where? Dave i do suppose that's a fair, but that's what the question is for

Comment: @MATHEMATICIAN Close-votes are disclosed when the question is actually closed. If you're using the web version (i.e. in a browser on a computer), there will be a large colored banner, just below the question, just above the comments on the question, saying "*This question was put on hold by X,Y,Z,P and Q for <reason>*". The *X,Y,Z,P, and Q* are the explicit usernames of the members of the community whose voted to close the question. If you have over 2K rep, you can also see when any question, even an open question,  has started to accrue close votes, and how many, but not by who.

Comment: There are no clear resolutions to any philosophical question that many philosophers can agree upon so all answers or comments or responses are just opinions that if 'favored' agree with some group or ' school of thought. If a comment or opinion is controversial it will probably not be favored by some established 'group' and ignored. Any philosophical group or organisation if honest would admit such a systematic bias against the unconventional even if expertly written.

Comment: @201044 yes I agree. It is almost impossible to get rid of a voting bias in a community such as this. I personally am more concerned with the speed at which questions are closed than the voting bias. But as I've said I don't see what can be done about it. I just know I've seen some pretty valid questions that could be answered get closed before anyone has a chance to answer them.

Comment: Not only are there inherent biases but if an editor's comment or response is not necessarily constructive and borders on personal challenges then any questioner will probably keep responding as emotionally defending themselves . So if these sites don't want long discussions it's just practical and efficient to keep editing policy constructive or at least not sounding confrontational....

Comment: I'll express it simply. I try to close questions quickly, because our biggest problem on this SE is the average quality of questions and answers. It scares away most with philosophical training, and we're left with inefficient answers to questions that are poorly worded. This SE is a *beta* and could get shut down at any time if the powers that be decide it isn't working.

Comment: Semantics vs. Syntax virmaior.

Comment: Semantics is more important than syntax? Did you read both color questions before marking the pair duplicate?

Comment: Yes, I did. I recognized they were not perfectly identical.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean when you keep saying "semantics vs. syntax" is that something your intro to phil professor was really interested in?

Comment: I know you have no idea, which quite frankly baffles me. I also find it hilarious.

Comment: how do you enter chat from comments?

Comment: " I recognized they were not perfectly identical." Not even close.

Comment: Well, you could try explaining in words what  you think "syntax vs. semantics" means / regarding chat, we've been there before and you basically stopped responding. / regarding your belief they're not identical: *noted*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28803/discussion-between-hellyale-and-virmaior).

Comment: Some user above said he tries to close questions quickly as many questions and answers scare away most with philosophical training. So if only fantastic questions are given fantastic answers and all the rest are of questionable quality then why do these websites say ' anybody can ask a question and anybody can answer? if the majority of questions are irritating these sites should NOT ADVERTISE to just anybody. As users above have admitted they see poor quality questions a lot....